# SQL query INSERT column count error

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have removed **'age_range'** from this query.

```
INSERT INTO `filters` (`id`, `user_id`, `profession_preference`, `country`, `city`, `order_by`, `profession_orientation`, `age_range`, `distance_range`, `location_dating`) VALUES
(9, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(10, 12, 3, 'Egypt', '', 2, 1, '', '', 0),
(11, 19, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(13, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(14, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(15, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(25, 121, 3, 'All Countries', '', 3, 1, '18,23', '0,500 ', 0),
(26, 316, 3, 'United States', '', 3, 1, '17,25', '0,500', 0);
```

I executed again and receive this error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: What is your interpretation of the error message?

Comment: You're trying to insert 10 values into 9 columns.  10 does not match 9.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you help me identify which value to remove?

Comment: Have you tried to run your updated question and do you get the same error?   if not what's the new error? I see 10/10 now.

Comment: To identify the value you want to remove, type out each one followed by the field it represents.  If you can't identify a field, that would be the value to remove.

Comment: If you look again, you see that I said that I have removed 'age_range' from the query and run it again.

Comment: I looked, age_range is still in the column headers and for ID 9 shows 16,100 as a value.  I still see 10 columns, 10 headers... so what's the error now, can't be the same.

Comment: @agis: You didn't remove `age_range`, you *added* `age_range`.  Given this miscommunication, I'm finding it unlikely that you're also communicating the updated error message effectively.  You should be getting a different error, or no error at all at this point.

Answer (score 2):

When you insert a record, it matches the values in the `VALUES` list to the columns in the columns list by comma-separated position. So, this insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (`A`, `B`, `C`)
VALUES ('valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC')
```

It will insert `valueA` into column `A`, `valueB` into column `B`, etc. because they match positions in their respective lists. If you remove `B` from the columns list and leave `VALUES` alone, it will not attempt to insert `valueA` into column `A`, but `valueB` into column `C` because they now match value positions, but it won't know what to do with `valueC` because there are now more values than columns, so since you removed the column from the second position, you would also need to remove the value from the second position.

So back to your query, you would need to determine which position `age_range` occupied in the columns list and remove the values from the same position in the `values` list.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I think it makes sense, however I will ask another question to be more clear about what I did, what I expect and what error I get.

Answer (score 1):

You have 9 columns defined in your insert statement and you are trying to insert 10 values.  you either need to add another column definition or remove from your values.

Comment: how can I know which one to remove or which one is extra?

Comment: @agis: Remove the one that you don't want to insert.  We don't know what your values represent.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you look over it now?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

According to rule the column name define and provided values count should be same. In your case one column value in extra.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you help me identify which value to remove?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says

> "Column count doesn't match value count"

You specify 9 columns (`id`, `user_id`, `profession_preference`, `country`, `city`, `order_by`, `profession_orientation`, `distance_range`, `location_dating`) in your insert statement
and you are trying to insert 10 values.

You have to remove one value or add another column

Comment: how can I know which one to remove or which one is extra?

Comment: I have updated my question, can you help me identify which value I need to remove?

Comment: if you removed "age_range, you should remove `'16,100'`, `'18,23', ect

Answer (score 0):

Before removing column this is the script which will work

```
CREATE TABLE filters (id INT, user_id INT, profession_preference INT, country VARCHAR(50), city VARCHAR(50), order_by INT, profession_orientation INT, age_range VARCHAR(50), distance_range VARCHAR(50), location_dating INT);

INSERT INTO filters (id, user_id, profession_preference, country, city, order_by, profession_orientation, age_range, distance_range, location_dating) VALUES
(9, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(10, 12, 3, 'Egypt', '', 2, 1, '', '', 0),
(11, 19, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(13, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(14, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(15, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '16,100', '0,500', 0),
(25, 121, 3, 'All Countries', '', 3, 1, '18,23', '0,500 ', 0),
(26, 316, 3, 'United States', '', 3, 1, '17,25', '0,500', 0);
```

Now since you removed age_range column, below script will work:

```
INSERT INTO filters (id, user_id, profession_preference, country, city, order_by, profession_orientation, distance_range, location_dating) VALUES
(9, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '0,500', 0),
(10, 12, 3, 'Egypt', '', 2, 1, '', 0),
(11, 19, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '0,500', 0),
(13, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '0,500', 0),
(14, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '0,500', 0),
(15, 20, 3, 'All Countries', '', 2, 1, '0,500', 0),
(25, 121, 3, 'All Countries', '', 3, 1, '0,500', 0),
(26, 316, 3, 'United States', '', 3, 1, '0,500', 0);
```

I removed third last column from insert script.

Hope this helps!